# Linq query filter by date (Month and year)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, lambda

```
public class content
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }  
}


Id   name       date
1    content1   01/01/2013
2    content2   05/01/2013
3    content3   05/03/2013
4    content4   01/06/2013
5    content5   10/03/2012
6    content6   01/01/2012
```

I'm trying that if query passes '01/2013', query should return  content id 1,2 .
Is there anyone knows how to query above situation ?

Comment: Is it Linq2SQL, Linq2Objects, Linq2Entities? - more details, please! ;-)

Answer (score 12):

Looks like you should be able to do:

```
// Type and property names changed to match .NET conventions
public IEnumerable<Content> GetContents(int year, int month)
{        
    return db.Contents // Or wherever you're getting data from
             .Where(c => c.Date.Year == year && c.Date.Month == month);
}
```

I've split out `year` and `month` as separate parameters, as that's how you *described* them - if you really want to be able to handle "01/2013" you would probably want to just split by `'/'` and parsing each of the pieces as an integer first. (Alternatively, parse it as a date in a specific format and then take the year and month from that.)

EDIT: Note that formatting each value as a string is pointless and potentially incorrect unless you're careful. (For example, unless you specify the culture explicitly, if you use `/` in the pattern you'll get the current culture's date separator, which may well not be what you expect.)

You're not actually trying to match a string pattern - you're trying to test for the year and month of the date. That's what the code above expresses clearly. String formatting is an irrelevance.

Answer (score 2):

This is correct for only moth and year

```
 List<eTransaction> lsttrans = db.eTransactions.Where(c => c.SchemeID == scid && 
    c.DateOfPay.Value.Month == month && c.DateOfPay.Value.Year == year).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suddenly worked out like below:

```
public IEnumerable<Content> GetContents(string date) /* E.G: date = '07/2013' */
{        
    return db.Contents // Or wherever you're getting data from
             .Where(c => c.Date.ToString("MM/yyyy") == date);
}
```

Is that right way to do ?

Comment: "Is that right way to do ?" - not in my view, no. You're not logically performing a string comparison; you're performing a month and year comparison. So convert your input data into a month and year first, and use those values to compare the month and year of each element.